# Unable to set selected value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i have several select boxes on my edit form, now when the page loads data is loaded into it, this works for all textboxes and checkboxes but not selectboxes, i am unable to set the selected value for them i have googled so many things but i still cannot seem to find what i am doing wrong, this is my html:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-init="getRoles()">
    <label for="roles">Role</label>
    <select style="width: 100%;" data-toggle="select2"  ng-model="form.role_id" ng-options="item.id as item.role for item in roles">
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the function that gets and sets the user info in my controller:

```
$scope.getUserInfo = function() {

    UserService.get($stateParams.id)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.user != undefined)
            {
                $scope.form = data.user;
            }
        })

};
```

This the function that gets and sets the roles in my controller:

```
$scope.getRoles = function() {

    RoleService.get()
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.roles != undefined)
            {
                $scope.roles = data.roles;
            }
        })


};
```

I have verified the returned data and it is indeed correct.
This is the returned JSON:

```
{"user":{"id":2,"email":"xxxxxxx@gmail.com","role_id":2,"institution_id":null,"is_active":1}}
```

And this is the returned roles JSON:

```
{"roles":[{"id":2,"role":"System"},{"id":3,"role":"Administrator"},{"id":4,"role":"Instructor"}]}
```

Comment: show your controller code. or fiddle create

Comment: Okay, i have done that now.

Comment: At first glance, this should work.

Comment: More code would be helpful!

Comment: More code from where? The service handles the $http request which returns the data which i have stated is correct, the controller assigns the returned data to the scope which i have shown in my code above, i bind my select to the scope as shown in the html above, i dunno what else to post here T^T

Comment: How does your roles array look like, and your 'form' object from ng-model..

Comment: Where and how do you check the selected ID?

Comment: Posted it, please check it.

Comment: Does your form tag have a name attribute?

Comment: My form tag or my select tag? Both do not.

Comment: Where do you define 'form.role_id'

Comment: I've updated my post and $scope.form is already defined in my code.

Comment: What is the output of {{form.role_id}}?

Comment: I think i have found the problem, it is from the template i purchased, apparently when i set the selected value it actually does work as i noticed when i checked the source, however it does not show because the jquery plugin used for the select has to be re-initialised or something, have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

`ng-model="user.role_id"`

Comment: Actually i have assigned data.users to $scope.form, lemme include that in my post.

Comment: How does this assignment look like?